# Can't create events on Meta Business Suite (web app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events, meta-business-suite

I was given access as an admin to a Facebook page. The page already has some created events, but I couldn't find a way to create new events for the page using the web app (business.facebook.com). I can create events with me as an organizer, but I can't switch to the page profile. The only way to manage the page is by using Meta Business Suite, but there is no option to create new events. There is an option called "Events Manager," but it's something related to website events, not what I'm looking for.

Interestingly, I can create events using the Meta Business Suite Android App, but after creating is impossible to edit or delete the events. If I try editing, it loads a blank page, and sometimes the app crashes; if I try to delete an event, it says, "Something went wrong."

I tried to follow some tutorials, but they always allow switching the FB profile before creating the event. I don't have that option. It seems the only way to manage the page is by using Meta Business Suite. I can create posts or messages, but not events.

Is there a reliable way to manage Facebook events for a page?